# jq - remove duplicate entries within all arrays inside the JSON file

Tags: arrays, json, search, jq

I have the following JSON file.

```
[
    {
        "name": "first",
        "Arrays": {
            "dddd0001": [
                "A",
                "A",
                "B",
                "B",
                "C",
                "C",
                "C",
                "C",
                "D",
                "E",
                "F"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "second",
        "Arrays": {
            "dddd0002": [
                "AA",
                "AA",
                "BA",
                "BB",
                "CC",
                "CC",
                "CC",
                "CC",
                "DD",
                "DD",
                "FF"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "third",
        "Arrays": {
            "dddd0003": [
                "1",
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "3",
                "4",
                "4",
                "4",
                "0",
                "0",
                "0"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I need to remove duplicates inside every array in the JSON file. So the result should look like following

```
[
    {
        "name": "first",
        "Arrays": {
            "dddd0001": [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C",
                "D",
                "E",
                "F"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "second",
        "Arrays": {
            "dddd0002": [
                "AA",
                "BA",
                "BB",
                "CC",
                "DD",
                "FF"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "third",
        "Arrays": {
            "dddd0003": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4",
                "0"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Array key names are not known in advance. There might be multiple arrays inside the `Arrays` object.
I tried to use `unique_by` but it requires the key name.

This algorithm - search for every array inside the Arrays object, for every such array apply `unique` function, re-assign results back to the array - should be fairly easy to implement, but I am stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
walk( if type == "array" then unique else . end)
```

If the original order should be respected, then you can easily use "def uniques" as defined at [How do I get jq to return unique results when json has multiple identical entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56626848/how-do-i-get-jq-to-return-unique-results-when-json-has-multiple-identical-entrie)

Comment: thanks for providing the solution - works perfectly. Do I understand correctly that ``uniqie`` not only sorts the array content but also arrays based on the array key name?

Comment: `unique` itself only sorts the array presented as its input.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `unique` and `|=`:

```
$ jq '.[].Arrays[] |= unique' file.json
[
  {
    "name": "first",
    "Arrays": {
      "dddd0001": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D",
        "E",
        "F"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "second",
    "Arrays": {
      "dddd0002": [
        "AA",
        "BA",
        "BB",
        "CC",
        "DD",
        "FF"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "third",
    "Arrays": {
      "dddd0003": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4"
      ]
    }
  }
]
$
```

the only "problem" is that `unique` sorts the elements of the array, so for example contents of `"dddd0003"` array are not in the same order of your expected result. I don't know if this is could be a problem for you.

if `"Arrays"` property can also contain "non-array" values, extra care can be taken in order to "filter out" those "non-array" values so that `unique` doesn't complain.

`select(type == "array")` can be used: (output omitted):

```
$ jq '(.[].Arrays[] | select(type == "array")) |= unique' file.json
...
```

or `arrays`:

```
$ jq '(.[].Arrays[] | arrays) |= unique' file.json
...
```

these last two solutions better reflect your algorithm.

Comment: Marco, thank you very much. It does address the problem, as long as the key name for the arrays - 'Arrays' in this case is known.

Comment: @Invisible999 yes, it's not a very "generic" solution in that sense I have to admit. glad I helped you a little :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jsonArr = [
    {
        "name": "first",
        "Arrays": {
            "dddd0001": [
                "A",
                "A",
                "B",
                "B",
                "C",
                "C",
                "C",
                "C",
                "D",
                "E",
                "F"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "second",
        "Arrays": {
            "dddd0002": [
                "AA",
                "AA",
                "BA",
                "BB",
                "CC",
                "CC",
                "CC",
                "CC",
                "DD",
                "DD",
                "FF"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "third",
        "Arrays": {
            "dddd0003": [
                "1",
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "3",
                "4",
                "4",
                "4",
                "0",
                "0",
                "0"
            ]
        }
    }
]


for(var i=0; i< jsonArr.length; i++)
{
var arrtemp =  jsonArr[i][Object.keys(jsonArr[i])[1]];

var arrtmp2 = arrtemp[Object.keys(arrtemp)[0]];

 jsonArr[i][Object.keys(jsonArr[i])[1]] =arrtmp2.filter((v, p) => arrtmp2.indexOf(v) == p);
 
 console.log(jsonArr[i])

}
```

Comment: Thanks but as it was said in the description, I am looking for a solution with jq.

Comment: oops. my mistake. sorry